# Input Type Date - Disable Everyday Except Monday (in ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I have the following App.js...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import moment from 'moment';

export default function App() {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({startDate: moment().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'), endDate: moment().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD')})

  const handleDateValueChange = (ev) => {
    setDateRange({...this.props.dateRange, [ev.target.name]: moment(ev.target.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')});
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="date" name="startDate" onChange={ev => handleDateValueChange(ev)} value={dateRange.startDate} />
      <input type="date" name="endDate" onChange={ev => handleDateValueChange(ev)} value={dateRange.endDate} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also view the code snippet here: https://codesandbox.io/s/date-moment-disable-days-ys3u1

[image]

I need all the days except mondays to be non-selectable (greyed out). Anyone have any idea how to do this in a react snippet?

---

Edit: I added the full code component and the codesandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot accomplish this with HTML5.

Check out [reactdatepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-21)

Here is the example that allows you to pick only Mondays:

```
<DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
    filterDate={date => getDay(date) === 1}
    placeholderText="Select a Monday"
/>
```

Updated version from your sandbox using moment and react-datepicker:

```
const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    startDate: new Date(moment().startOf("isoweek").utc()),
    endDate: new Date(moment().endOf("week").utc())
});

<DatePicker
      selected={new Date(dateRange.startDate)}
      onChange={(date) => setDateRange({ ...dateRange, startDate: date })}
      name="startDate"
      filterDate={(date) => date.getDay() === 1}
      placeholderText="Select a Monday"
    />
```

Comment: if you change your answer to match the following: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-s73wx. I can mark it as correct and give you the points. Note: I also had to pull in the .css from the date picker or the calendar wouldn't show.

Comment: Good point on the css. I remember using it for the first time, everything was all over the place.